# Cordova Ionic app in Visual Studio 2017 iOS remote build

Tags: ios, cordova

After a week of messing around with my setup to build the Android version with SDK 32, I been struggling with iOS remote build for days, I'm stuck on the error below.

If anyone can suggest anything or a setup which works I would be very grateful.

My setup is

Windows 10 - Visual Studio 2017 Professional 2017 v15.9.51

SDK Build Tool: 32.0.0

Cordova 11.1.0
android 10.1.2
ios 6.2.0
node    14.17.3 (I've also tried 13.14.0 & 18.13.0 LTS)

npm     9.1.2 (I've also tried 6.14.13, 7.7.6 & 8.1.0)
java    11.0.17

The apple Mac is running Ventura 13. / Xcode 14.2, its viewable on the network and has previously been working for years

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: The "VsTac" task failed unexpectedly.
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\appAsTgz.tgz'.
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018: File name: 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\appAsTgz.tgz'
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode)
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.AppAsTgzStream(String changeTimeFile, JObject lastChangeTimesMap)
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.RemoteBuild.Build()
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.VsTac.BuildPlatform()
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.VisualStudio.MultiDeviceHybridApps.MdaBuildTasks.VsTac.Execute()
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
D:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\ApacheCordovaTools\vs-mda-targets\Microsoft.MDA.FileMirroring.targets(256,5): error MSB4018:    at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:02.41
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Trying to build the iOS version of Cordova Mobile App

Comment: as your error has to do with the machine not being able to find a file (` Could not find file 'C:\Users\myuser\AppData\Local\Temp\appAsTgz.tgz'.`). I think it would be helpful to add the code where you store that file and subsequently look for that file. or something similar. It's hard to give suggestions without it. Also, is android working and only iOS failing? did it work before?

Comment: I've searched the entire project for appAsTgz.tgz and there is no reference to it. Android is working and iOS worked previously for several years.